# WPF C# standard design patterns

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, design-patterns

I'm fairly new to `WPF`, `C#`, and the `.Net framework`, having had a mainly Linux programming background. Having started a new job around a month ago I've been tasked with helping a colleague extend an app he's been working on for a customer. The app has many different pages with different functions.

My understanding of `WPF` was that to handle this you would create a view for different pages (a `.xaml` file) and also make a corresponding ViewModel (a `.xaml.cs` file) and switch between these views as the user navigates through the app.

However, the app that I'm working on has one very large partial class (~5000 lines) split over several files. With only a few `.xaml` and `.xaml.cs` files representing some of the paths that a user can take. Within the `xaml` there are several `ControlTemplates` defined, and then `DataTriggers` are used to switch between the `ControlTemplates` as various `enums` are changed in the code.

This feels like quite a clumsy way to design the code, as the feature that I'm putting in doesn't have a linear "one page after another" kind of structure that other areas of the app do.

I was just wondering if this kind of thing was standard? I feel like the code has been badly designed but I'm new and inexperienced.

Comment: google MVVM MVPVM WPF

Comment: Yes there might be something wrong (Bad smells in code, chapter 3 in Refactoring) Have a look at MVVM and ask any specific questions here.

Comment: A 5000 lines partial class file *is* a bad design, in whatever pattern they are supposed to be using.

Comment: Did you even Google "prism patterns and practices"? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg406140.aspx *Using design patterns that embody important architectural design principles, such as separation of concerns and loose coupling, Prism helps you to design and build applications using loosely coupled components that can evolve independently but which can be easily and seamlessly integrated into the overall application.*

Comment: @ta.speot.is, No I didn't Google that, as I mentioned I'm new to Windows development so it would have taken a stroke of extreme good fortune to construct such a search query with no prior knowledge of something called prism. However, thanks for the tip, I've googled it and it seems like it'll be helpful.

Comment: I would suggest just reading up on design patterns generally, for any mainstream OO language. If you've 5,000 lines in a single class, then there's a major issue, as you already know.

You seem to be keen to do things the right way. I think understanding some of the 'SOLID' principles would help you, certainly SRP. As for MVVM, I think it might be running before you can walk. MVVM isn't easy to get your head around even for OO developers, and might put you off learning at all.